# Return Rails app to development mode with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I've deployed my app to a remote machine using Capistrano and Passenger. The project is on GitHub, and I want to work on some bug fixes on my local machine.  I've synced up everything, and branched to a new 'dev' branch on my local machine. When I try the simple `rails server` command I had been using while developing, I get errors relating to the gems bundled in my Gemfile, e.g. `` `require': no such file to load -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError) ``.  But when I run `bundle show nokogiri`, it's present at `/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0`.

Maybe this is just the wrong workflow entirely, but how do I get to a development mode on my local machine, so I can test changes before pushing them to the deployed app?

My Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.10'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:

gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'nested_scaffold'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'pony'
gem 'mail'
gem 'logger'
gem 'json'
gem 'gmail'


# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you delete `.bundle` directory (consider backing up whatever's inside `.bundle/config` first) and run your bundle install command again.  You can do `cat .bundle/config` to echo its contents to your terminal (STDOUT).

Make sure you have chosen the correct gemset by doing `rvm gemdir` and `gem list` to see all the gems in the current gemset.

Start your server with `rails s -e development` (s is short for server)

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Is this something I'll have to do every time after pushing a new update to production?

Comment: On my development system I tend to do `bundle install --without=production` that way all gems listed in `:production` are ignored.  If you were to add the original contents of `.bundle/config` I would be able to give you a better suggestion.