# Redeploying Rails app results in new bundling error with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, bundler

I deployed my first rails app to a production server a few days ago.  Since then, I've been working on some fixes on my development machine and I pushed those over to the production server via git.  I touched the `restart.txt` file and then restarted Apache, and now I'm getting a Passenger error that I think is related to gems and bundle.

When I first started development I ran into an issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406059/return-rails-app-to-development-mode-with-bundler)) and I removed the `.bundle` directory.  I then ran `bundle install` again on my development machine, and all seemed well while I fixed some bugs.

Now I'm ready to redeploy the next version of the app, and after these errors, I checked and noticed that I don't even have a `.bundle` directory anymore.  `bundle install` doesn't create a new one.  I assume nothing's going to work without that?  Should I just manually create the requisite files or is there a command to regenerate those?

EDIT to add error: `syntax error on line 3, col 2:  adapter:sqlite3'`

`database.yml`:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
gem install sqlite3
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Hi Paul, what's the error exactly?

Comment: The error lists:  syntax error on line 3, col 2: ` adapter:sqlite3'

Comment: No, not having a .bundle directory should be fine but the general rule is not to check it into your repo.  It should be marked in your .gitignore file as well - this way your development machine can have one bundler config, and your production systems can have their own.  Try deleting the vendor/cache directory as well - see if you can get your app to run off the gems in your gemset; double check your deployment .rvmrc as well.

Comment: I hope you're not running production with sqlite! :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `gem install sqlite3` in your listing of `database.yml` actually present in that file? If that is the case than that is the cause of the error as it is invalid YAML. Also, the statement doesn't make sense here, as the file isn't interpreted by neither bundler nor ruby.

At best, just remove (or comment) that statement there and try gain.

Edit: Generally, whitespace (especially leading whitespace) is rather important in YAML. Don't mix spaces and tabs here. It would confuse the parser. Also there need to be a space between the key and the value in a hash like so

```
key: value
#   ^ this space is important!
```

Please refer to [YAML's Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) for more info about YAML syntax.

Comment: Good grief, it's working now. I honestly don't even know why that was in there to begin with. I've mostly been following tutorials up to this point.  Thanks!

Comment: Yup, that's the issue I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

@Paul, can you try updating your gemfile as follows

```
group :production do
  # gem 'mysql2' # disabled to debug Paul's issue.
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

Let me know how this pans out.

Comment: I added the lines.  I wasn't sure what to do next but I ran `bundle install` and it installed mysql2. I actually was using sqlite3 for production as I didn't know any better.  I'm still getting the same Passenger error, however.

Comment: I have a sneaky feeling [it's your database.yml file](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/132648).  Mind pasting it up?  To debug this further comment out the mysql2 bit and move sqlite to it - I'll update the code above to reflect it.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that link as well.  I pasted the file contents above.  Interestingly, before this error, I was getting a yaml error that was resolved by placing `require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'` in my `boot.rb` file.